# Creating a Mongo replicaset in a CircleCI job

Tags: mongodb, docker, continuous-integration, yaml, circleci

I am trying to run integration tests in CircleCI on code that makes use of MongoDB Transactions. I am currently getting the following error:

`(IllegalOperation) Transaction numbers are only allowed on a replica set member or mongos`

Is there a way to initiate a replicaset before running the tests?

I have tried using `docker exec` to run commands on the container without any success.

Has anyone managed to do this before?

Currently my circleci config file looks like this:

```
 integration:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/golang:1.13
      - image: circleci/mongo:3
    steps:
      - attach_workspace:
          at: .

      - run: go test ./... -mod vendor -v -race -tags integration
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first off, you need to initialize mongod as a replica set. The docker: section takes a command tag that can be run at start up

```
- image: circleci/mongo:4.0
  command: [--replSet,rs0]
```

now the mongo container will automatically start up as a replSet. However you aren't out of the weeds yet. You still need to run rs.Initiate(), and that must be run outside of the mongo container (since it is running the mongod server).

Whenever you use `run` it relates to the first container, which in this case is the golang container. You need to install the mongo-cli in that container and then run rs.initiate()

In my case, I was running an Alpine docker container and resolved it with this code

```
  - run:
    name: "Initialize Replica Set"
    command: |
      echo 'http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.6/main' >> /etc/apk/repositories
      echo 'http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.6/community' >> /etc/apk/repositories
      apk update
      apk add mongodb=3.4.4-r0
      mongo mongodb://localhost:27017 --eval "rs.initiate()"
```

However I think the circle:golang containers are running off of Debian. According to [this blog](https://tecadmin.net/install-mongodb-server-on-debian/) it looks like you can run

```
  - run:
    name: "Initialize Replica Set"
    command: |
      echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian "$(lsb_release -sc)"/mongodb-org/4.0 main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list
      sudo apt-get update
      sudo apt-get install mongodb-org
      mongo mongodb://localhost:27017 --eval "rs.initiate()"
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! I had to make a small change to the commands for Debian containers:
```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 9DA31620334BD75D9DCB49F368818C72E52529D4
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian stretch/mongodb-org/4.0 main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mongodb-org-shell
mongo mongodb://localhost:27017 --eval "rs.initiate()"
```